# Is it possible to get a group from Matcher using $x?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to do the following:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(AMReg.LocLink.regEx()).matcher(input);

if(m.find()) {
 urlStr = URLEncoder.encode(m.group(AMReg.LocLink.getPlace(1)), "US-ASCII");
}
```

AMReg is an enum. `regEx()` returns the regex to search for and `getPlace(x)` returns the group number to get generally used in a replaceAll, so it's `$1` or `$2` instead of a standard integer that is used in m.group(x);

Is it possible to use the `$2` field to return the matched group from Matcher? [I searched through the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html), but couldn't find a way to do it.

*(Also, what is the `$2` group number called? Using the $?)*

Comment: The strings `"$1"`, `"$2"`, etc., are only useful in `replace` and methods like that.  `m.group` needs an `int` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Matcher.group (int groupNum)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29):

```
m.group ( AMReg.LocLink.getPlace() );
```

Where `AMReg.LocLink.getPlace()` returns a group # 1, 2 etc.

Comment: Yeah, it's not an integer. It's a string with the `$`. I guess I could just parse out the `$`... I feel that there is a better way to do it though. Maybe it's just friday.

Comment: Yes you can easily strip `$` if you cannot change code in `getPlace` method.

Comment: I think I'm just going to bite the bullet and redesign the enum & class where `getPlace(n);` adds a `$` to the int and returns a string, throw in another function to return the raw int. Thanks for letting me know what I wanted to do wasn't possible. This is my first time using Matcher so I didn't know that would cause a problem when I designed it.